# While using nested <ul> and <ol> in HTML, I am facing problem with the line spacing

Tags: html, css, tags, html-lists

I am using very basic HTML for my college assignment, where I had to use nested `<ul> and <ol>.` All is okay, but there is just a problem of line spacing - as you can see in the image, the first `<li>`item in `<ul>` did not leave a line, like other elements, which ruins my format.

Is there any way to solve this without using CSS, or just 1-2 lines of it.

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      
<title>GEC Modasa </title>
</head> 
 <body>
 <ol>
 <li><b>COMPUTER ENGINEERING</b>
 <ol type = "a">
     <li>WEB DEVELOPMENT</li>
     <li>SOFTWARE ENGINEERING</li>
     <li>ADVANCED JAVA</li>
 </ol>
</li>      
     
 <li><b>INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</b>
 <ol type = "I">
     <li>DISTRIBUTED OS</li>
     <li>IMAGE PROCESSING</li>
     <li>.NET</li>  
 </ol> </li> 

<li><b>CIVIL ENGINEERING</b>
<ul type="square">
    <li> APPLIED FLUID MECHANICS</li>
    <li>WATER & WATERWASTE ENGINEERING</li>
 </ul> </li> 
 
</ol>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wRmD.png)

It is solved. Just problem with my browser

Comment: CSS is the presentation language of the WWW. If you care about how your webpages look: Use CSS.

Comment: **Danger**: Screen readers tend to treat ALL CAPS as initialisms that need to be spelt out letter-by-letter. Never type phrases in ALL CAPS, use the CSS `text-transform` property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied your code and run it, everything is looking nice/ there is no error. May be I recommend you have to reRun your html code in a different browser, may be I recommend google chrome.
If you want to to make a line space you can use the break statement, 
 or .

Answer (score -2):

I wish to put the code Live to check it in a practical way but you can target the first child of any ul or ol with this way :

```
ul li:first-child {
margin-top:5px // margin-top
 }


ol li:first-child {
margin-top:5px // margin-top
 }

ul {
line-height:1.8; // more spacing will be more line height 
}
```